# SQLiteConnection DisposedObject

Tags: c#, sqlite, exception

```
class SQLiteDatabase
    {
        String dbConnection;
        static SQLiteConnection cnn;
        static int connections = 0;
        /// <summary>
        ///     Default Constructor for SQLiteDatabase Class.
        /// </summary>
        public SQLiteDatabase()
        {
            dbConnection = "Data Source=SQLiteOphthaMetrics.db;foreign keys=true;";
            if (connections == 0)
            {
                cnn = new SQLiteConnection(dbConnection);
                cnn.Open();
                this.ExecuteNonQuery("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS patients ( id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT NOT NULL, birthday TEXT, gender TEXT, iriscolor INTEGER);");
                this.ExecuteNonQuery("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS images ( nameRed TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, checksumRed TEXT NOT NULL, "
                    + "nameGreen TEXT NOT NULL, checksumGreen TEXT NOT NULL, state INTEGER, cvalue REAL, sharpness REAL, deviation REAL, area REAL, redExposure REAL, "
                    + "redGain REAL, greenExposure REAL, greenGain REAL, zfocus INTEGER, flipped INTEGER, patientID INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY (patientID) REFERENCES patients(id));");
            }
            connections++;
        }

        ~SQLiteDatabase()
        {
            connections--;
            if (connections == 0)
            {
                cnn.Close();
                cnn.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

This code throws a DisposedObjectException

```
System.ObjectDisposedException was unhandled
  Message=Auf das verworfene Objekt kann nicht zugegriffen werden.
Objektname: "SQLiteConnection".
  Source=System.Data.SQLite
  ObjectName=SQLiteConnection
  StackTrace:
       bei System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection.CheckDisposed()
       bei System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection.Close()
       bei EyeScanner.SQLiteDatabase.Finalize()
  InnerException:
```

I am calling SQLiteDatabase currently only a single time in the code, thus connections = 1 in the destructor, but I do not understand why it would dispose the object before the class destructor is finished.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you are trying to dispose the connection once the class instance is ready for dispose. It would be better if you use `using` statement with your SQLiteConnection. SQLiteConnection class implements IDisposable and you will be able to do the following:

```
using(cnn = new SQLiteConnection(dbConnection))
{
     cnn.Open();
     this.ExecuteNonQuery("...your query");
}
```

This will act as a `try/finally` block, and even if an exception occurs, the connection will be closed and disposed after the `using` block.

**With respect to Database connection, the best approach is to open as late as possible and close as early as possible.**

Comment: But the cnn.Open() actually takes quite a lot of time to perform. Is it really intended to have this on .Close() as often as possible? It takes like half a second, and if I need to do that every time I read the DB that kinda stinks...

Comment: Okay, correction, only the first Open() takes that long, every following is fast. Will do so, I got no more exception now.

Comment: Also consider implementing [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) interface on class and dispose the resources in `Dispose` method, instead of using Destructors

Comment: Okay, will do that. I am used to C++ programming, and C# is only used for the GUI, but it needs the database access, thus I am a little lost there ;)